# How can I build a GraphicsGrid of fixed size that rearranges the empty plots?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, grid-layouts

OK, let's make one final attempt; they say the third time is the lucky one! Following @rm-rf 's suggestions, I will try to be as clear as I can.

My Mathematica code reads and plots simultaneously some data files. The output of the function `plo` below can be either a `Graphics` object (`ListPlot`) or a null string (`""`) if the data it reads doesn't exist. I want to arrange the 20 plots below in a grid of fixed dimensions ($  4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 2 \times 2$) like so:

```
P0 = Show[GraphicsGrid[{
{plo[1, 1], plo[2, 1], plo[4, 1], plo[7, 1]},
{plo[1, 2], plo[3, 1], plo[5, 1], plo[7, 2]},
{plo[1, 3], plo[3, 2], plo[6, 1], plo[8, 1]},
{plo[1, 4], plo[3, 3], plo[6, 2], plo[8, 2]},
{plo[1, 5], plo[3, 4]},
{plo[1, 6], plo[3, 5]}}]]
```

Since some data files may not exist, I would like the plots to rotate so that there are no blank spaces in between the plots but all the `Null` plots get moved to the end of the grid. For example, if `plo[2, 1]`, `plo[7, 2]` are missing I would like them to take up the last two slots in my grid while the rest of the plots preserve their ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here goes (again). (Probably) replacing this line:

```
P0 = Show[GraphicsGrid[{
{plo[1, 1], plo[2, 1], plo[4, 1], plo[7, 1]},
{plo[1, 2], plo[3, 1], plo[5, 1], plo[7, 2]},
{plo[1, 3], plo[3, 2], plo[6, 1], plo[8, 1]},
{plo[1, 4], plo[3, 3], plo[6, 2], plo[8, 2]},
{plo[1, 5], plo[3, 4]},
{plo[1, 6], plo[3, 5]}}
```

with this

```
Module[{list, newlist},
list=Select[Flatten[{
{plo[1, 1], plo[2, 1], plo[4, 1], plo[7, 1]},
{plo[1, 2], plo[3, 1], plo[5, 1], plo[7, 2]},
{plo[1, 3], plo[3, 2], plo[6, 1], plo[8, 1]},
{plo[1, 4], plo[3, 3], plo[6, 2], plo[8, 2]},
{plo[1, 5], plo[3, 4]},
{plo[1, 6], plo[3, 5]}}],! StringQ@#&];
newlist=PadRight[list,20,Null];
GraphicsGrid[{newlist[[1;;4]],newlist[[5;;8]],newlist[[9;;12]],newlist[[13;;16]],newlist[[17;;18]],newlist[[19;;20]]}]
]
```

will work

Comment: Yes it's working!!! If a plot is missing does it replace it with the first next available plot or it reconfigures the grid randomly?

Comment: it reconfigures the grid so that the shape of the grid is as close to a square as possible (adding blank plots at the end)

Comment: I found a drawback. If all files are present then it produces a 5x4 grid not the standard 4x4, 2x2. Why?

Comment: Is it possible to keep the 4x4, 2x2 structure and fill the blank slots with the next available plot? It does not matter to me if the shape of the grid is square or not; but the position of the plots are important.

Comment: I just edited it to do that but surely you know how to rearrange a list yourself. I am really not going to deal with this any further.

Comment: I am getting n error using the edited module.

Comment: `part` variable seems undefined. Also I do not understand the double , in `GraphicsGrid`

Comment: Just now I realized what causes the wrong grid structure. If a plot is missing its place is being replaced by the next available plot from the same row! Is it possible to use the next plot right below it from the next row?

Comment: Vaggeli, I have edited the obvious typos on my solution and I am not dealing with this any longer. I also edited your question heavily to what I think it should be - if the edit gets accepted by the moderators and you are happy with it please use it as a guideline for the future.

Comment: Not even a last shot? I am convinced you are so close to the solution. The only thing left is the replacement. Take the plot right below it from the next column not that of the same row. In other words make a vertical relocation rather horizontal.